# Type-level arithmetic: "at most" nat or nat interval

Tags: ocaml, type-level-computation

Using type-level arithmetic in OCaml, it's easy to define a function which takes a nat higher than a specific value:

```
let f : 'a succ nat -> string = function _ -> "hej"
f Zero (* <-- Won't compile, argument must be > 0 *)
```

Is there any way to make the function accept "at most" a value, or an interval, like 0 < n < 10?

Btw, this is the type definitions:

```
type z = Z
type 'n succ = S of 'n
type ( 'n) nat = 
  | Zero : ( z) nat
  | Succ : ( 'n) nat -> ( 'n succ) nat
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to use polymorphic variants.

```
let g : [`A0 of z nat | `A1 of (z succ) nat ] -> string = function
  _ -> "hej"
```

It's definitely not beautiful like your example, though it is fairly flexible if you can stand the syntactic burden.

Answer (score 3):

How about the following?

By using open polymorphic variants we can write a function that can only be applied on 1,3 and 4. It would obviously be quite unwieldy to write constraints for very large numbers.

First, let's define our `nat` type and the numbers one to five:

```
# type _ nat =
    Zero : [> `Zero] nat
  | Succ : 'a nat -> [> `Succ of 'a] nat;;
type _ nat = Zero : [> `Zero ] nat | Succ : 'a nat -> [> `Succ of 'a ] nat

# let one = Succ Zero;;
val one : [> `Succ of [> `Zero ] ] nat = Succ Zero

# let two = Succ one;;
val two : [> `Succ of [> `Succ of [> `Zero ] ] ] nat = Succ (Succ Zero)

# let three = Succ two;;
val three : [> `Succ of [> `Succ of [> `Succ of [> `Zero ] ] ] ] nat =
  Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))

# let four = Succ three;;
val four :
  [> `Succ of [> `Succ of [> `Succ of [> `Succ of [> `Zero ] ] ] ] ] nat =
  Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero)))

# let five = Succ four;;
val five :
  [> `Succ of
       [> `Succ of [> `Succ of [> `Succ of [> `Succ of [> `Zero ] ] ] ] ] ]
  nat = Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))))
```

Now let's define some types for representing our restrictions:

```
# type 'a no = [`Succ of 'a];;
type 'a no = [ `Succ of 'a ]

# type 'a yes = [ `Succ of 'a | `Zero ];;
type 'a yes = [ `Succ of 'a | `Zero ]

# type last = [ `Zero ];;
type last = [ `Zero ]
```

Using these types we can express a number that is 1,3 or 4 as `(last yes no yes no) nat`. Here `no` means don't allow this number, whilst `yes` and `last` mean do allow this number. Note that we are counting from the right-hand side.

Now we can define our function. Note that we only need to include cases for the numbers in our function's domain:

```
# let f (x : (last yes no yes no) nat) = 
        match x with
        Succ Zero -> "1"
      | Succ (Succ (Succ Zero)) -> "3"
      | Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))) -> "4";;
val f : last yes no yes no nat -> string = <fun>
```

Finally, we can try out our function on the numbers one to five, getting some nice large error messages for incorrect usage:

```
# f Zero;;
Characters 2-6:
  f Zero;;
    ^^^^
Error: This expression has type ([> `Zero ] as 'a) nat
       but an expression was expected of type last yes no yes no nat
       Type 'a is not compatible with type
         last yes no yes no = [ `Succ of last yes no yes ] 
       The second variant type does not allow tag(s) `Zero

# f one;;
- : string = "1"

# f two;;
Characters 2-5:
  f two;;
    ^^^
Error: This expression has type
         ([> `Succ of [> `Succ of [> `Zero ] as 'c ] as 'b ] as 'a) nat
       but an expression was expected of type last yes no yes no nat
       Type 'a is not compatible with type
         last yes no yes no = [ `Succ of last yes no yes ] 
       Type 'b is not compatible with type
         last yes no yes = [ `Succ of last yes no | `Zero ] 
       Type 'c is not compatible with type
         last yes no = [ `Succ of last yes ] 
       The second variant type does not allow tag(s) `Zero

# f three;;
- : string = "3"

# f four;;
- : string = "4"

# f five;;
Characters 2-6:
  f five;;
    ^^^^
Error: This expression has type
         ([> `Succ of
               [> `Succ of
                    [> `Succ of
                         [> `Succ of [> `Succ of [> `Zero ] ] as 'e ] as 'd ]
                    as 'c ]
               as 'b ]
          as 'a)
         nat
       but an expression was expected of type last yes no yes no nat
       Type 'a is not compatible with type
         last yes no yes no = [ `Succ of last yes no yes ] 
       Type 'b is not compatible with type
         last yes no yes = [ `Succ of last yes no | `Zero ] 
       Type 'c is not compatible with type
         last yes no = [ `Succ of last yes ] 
       Type 'd is not compatible with type
         last yes = [ `Succ of last | `Zero ] 
       Type 'e is not compatible with type last = [ `Zero ] 
       The second variant type does not allow tag(s) `Succ
```